# different INTERFACE compiler options for different languages

Tags: c++, cmake, build, cuda, multilingual

CMake, as of v3.20, has the [`target_compile_options()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html), which we can invoke, for example, like so:

```
target_compile_options(foo INTERFACE "--some-option")
```

which is well and good... as long as we're only using foo in compilations in a single language, or even with a single compiler. But what if I want to depend on `foo` in compilations in different language? e.g. C, C++ and CUDA?

How can I indicate different compilation options for use by such dependents for different languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a generator expression that works for you: `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:languages>` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#id2)

I haven't tried this out in your scenario though.

```
target_compile_options(foo INTERFACE
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:--option-for-C>"
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:--option-for-C++>"
    ...
)
```

From the documentation:

> `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:languages>`
>
> `1` when the language used for compilation unit matches any of the entries in `languages`, otherwise `0`. This expression may be used to specify compile options, compile definitions, and include directories for source files of a particular language in a target.

Comment: But are you sure this doesn't refer to the compilation language of foo?

Comment: @einpoklum - fabian is right. This answer is correct. An individual target doesn't have a compile language (it does have a linker language, though), only sources do.

Comment: @AlexReinking: So to clarify, the answer to my previous comment is "No, these options will be added when compiling foo in each respective language?"

Comment: @einpoklum - right. For each source file, it will check which compiler is being used to produce the object file and evaluate the generator expression in that context. C sources will get flags guarded by `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>` and C++ sources will get flags guarded by `$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My thought at the moment is to use dummy targets, each with its own INTERFACE compilation options:

```
add_custom_target( foo_c    )
add_custom_target( foo_cpp  )
add_custom_target( foo_cuda )
add_dependencies( foo_c    foo )
add_dependencies( foo_cpp  foo )
add_dependencies( foo_cuda foo )
target_compile_options( foo_c    INTERFACE "--option-for-C"    )
target_compile_options( foo_cpp  INTERFACE "--option-for-C++"  )
target_compile_options( foo_cuda INTERFACE "--option-for-CUDA" )
```

but that seems like a kludge.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. Do what fabian suggested.